# lock vs Interlocked.Exchange

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, task, interlocked

I have an application which constantly (+-100ms) reads orders from a PLC and then puts them in a model which then gets read by multiple clients.
For this im using the lock statement.

Order Reading thread :

```
lock (model) {
//update object
}
```

Clients Reading :

```
lock (model) {
//serialize object to json string
}
send over tcp stream to client.
```

But i could also use for the update :

```
Interlocked.ExChange(oldObj, newObj)
```

I don't want my clients to have to wait for a lock that is happening in the Order Reading thread.
And i definitly dont want client to block my Order Reading thread.

Am i better off using the Interlocked ?

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are better off using `Interlocked` as it's more efficient since it's mostly translated into a single atomic operation.

However, if you don't mind the clients still reading the old object for a bit you can even do without the Interlocked and just set a new instance.

The client that happen to get the new instance will get the updated data and those that don't will get it in one of the next checks.

Comment: So i can just lose the locks arround the client requests and use interlocked to change my cross-thread variable ?

Answer (score 2):

If your single producer is creating a brand new model, and assigning it to a shared field, then yes, `Interlocked.Exchange` is the way to go here.

If your producer does not need to know what the *old* model was, then you could use `Volatile.Write(ref _sharedObj, newObj)` instead to keep it simpler.

Just be aware of 3 things:

1. Use `Volatile.Read` to read your shared object.
2. The consumers should read the shared state *once* per unit of work

   ```
   //incorrect - _sharedObj is not guaranteed to be the same in both reads
   var x = CalculateX(_sharedObj);
   var y = CalculateY(_sharedObj);

   //correct
   var obj = Volatile.Read(ref _sharedObj);
   var x = CalculateX(obj);
   var y = CalculateY(obj);
   ```
3. The consumers will sometimes be using a slightly outdated model. So be sure that using a slightly outdated object doesn't cause you any trouble

   ```
   var obj = _sharedObj;
   // If _sharedObj is exchanged here, then `obj` will be outdated
   var x = CalculateX(obj);
   var y = CalculateY(obj);
   ```

Comment: Hi, in that case it's easier to use Interlocked since that only requires me to do 1 operation instead of volatile where i'm required to do read/write.      Another question : when using the Interlocked can   i lose the lock on the client requests ? I dont care if they have 1 iteration of old data. Thanks!

Comment: @user2565518 Yes - if the model is immutable (the object itself, not the reference to it), then the client can simply make a copy of the reference (e.g. `var obj = _sharedObj`) and work with that.

Comment: Why does it need to make a reference copy ?

Comment: point 2 talks about using Volatile.read, not about the Interlocked scenario to switch values and users not using synclock.

Comment: @user2565518 Point 2 states that reading the shared reference twice may result in different values - and that's why you need to make a copy of the reference upfront, and then use that copy.