# How to measure interval between two calls of a method without using a lock?

Tags: c#, performance, time, parallel-processing, locking

I have a function which needs to return the precise amount of time that passed since it was called last. Currently, it's implemented like this:

```
    public TimeSpan Span()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var r = now - lastCallTime;
            lastCallTime = now;
            return r;
        }
    }
```

My issue with this method is that it uses lock, which can have significant performance impact.

Is a way of implementing this without using locks altogether?

Comment: `DateTime` is only accurate to around 50ms, so that's not going to be good enough anyway. You should be using `Stopwatch`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson noted, thanks!

Comment: @mjwills I'm using this combined with  randomization to make software perform different actions with set time frequencies. Implementing it like this allows me not to store state information. The less precise the interval, the more what the software does will deviate from what I tell it to do

Comment: How often will `lock` face contention? 1% of the time? 70%?

Comment: @mjwills this is a part of a library I'm going to be re-using over and over again. If there is a way to implement this without locking, I'd like to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using:

```
public long lastTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

public TimeSpan Span()
{
    do
    {
        long oldValue = lastTimestamp;
        long currentTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

        var previous = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref lastTimestamp, currentTimestamp, oldValue);

        if (previous == oldValue)
        {
            // We effectively 'got the lock'
            var ticks = (currentTimestamp - oldValue) * 10_000_000 / Stopwatch.Frequency;
            return new TimeSpan(ticks);
        }
    } while (true);

    // Will never reach here
    // return new TimeSpan(0);
}
```

This will be thread-safe without the need for an explicit `lock`. And if there is contention on `lastTimestamp` then the code will loop until it works. *This does mean that multiple calls to `Span` may not 'finish' in the same order that they 'started'.*

A simpler approach to consider (but see the caveat below) would be:

```
public long lastTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

public TimeSpan Span()
{
    long currentTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

    var previous = Interlocked.Exchange(ref lastTimestamp, currentTimestamp);

    var ticks = (currentTimestamp - previous) * 10_000_000 / Stopwatch.Frequency;

    return new TimeSpan(ticks);
}
```

This will be thread-safe without the need for an explicit `lock`. `Interlocked.Exchange` *generally* [outperforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121684/lock-vs-interlocked-exchange) `lock`.

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.exchange?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Interlocked_Exchange_System_Int64__System_Int64_), `Interlocked.Exchange`:

> Sets a 64-bit signed integer to a specified value and returns the
>   original value, as an atomic operation.

This code is simpler, but due to the way that `Interlocked.Exchange` works (see Matthew Watson's great answer), the `TimeSpan` returned might be **negative** in high contention scenarios. *This will not occur with the first solution, but the first solution will be slower with high contention.*

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, I want to show you how the simpler code (second solution) from the accepted answer *could* return a negative value, as noted in that answer.

This thought-experiment uses two threads, designated T1 and T2. I'm prefixing the stack variables with T1 and T2 so you can tell them apart (below).

Let's assume that lastTimeStamp starts at 900 and the current time is 1000.

Now consider the following interlaced thread operations:

```
T1: long currentTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp(); 
    => T1:currentTimeStamp = 1000
T2: long currentTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp(); 
    => T2:currentTimeStamp = 1010
T2: var previous = Interlocked.Exchange(ref lastTimestamp, T2:currentTimestamp);
    => T2:previous = 900, lastTimestamp = 1010
T1: var previous = Interlocked.Exchange(ref lastTimestamp, T1:currentTimestamp);
    => T1:previous = 1010, lastTimestamp = 1000
T1: var ticks = (T1:currentTimestamp - T1:previous)
    => ticks = 1000 - 1010 = -10
T2: var ticks = (T2:currentTimestamp - T2:previous)
    => ticks = 1010 - 900 = 110
```

As you can see, thread T1 will end up returning -10.

---

[Addendum]

Here's my take on it - I'm not bothering to convert the stopwatch timestamp to a TimeSpan; I'm just leaving it in the units returned from `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` for brevity (and it will be slightly quicker):

```
public static long Span()
{
    long previous;
    long current;

    do
    {
        previous = lastTimestamp;
        current = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
    }
    while (previous != Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref lastTimestamp, current, previous));

    return current - previous;
}

static long lastTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
```

This is the same solution as the accepted answer above, just organised slightly differently.